# Laravel 5.8 npm run dev generating an ENOENT error

Tags: npm, laravel-5.8, adminlte, enoent

I need to run "npm run dev" in order to update the bootstrap and jquery in a Laravel 5.8 web app but it contantly generating the following error...

```
(node:4758) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:1115:3)
    at Object.lstatSync (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:311:34)
    at statFunc (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/util/stat.js:24:20)
    at getStatsSync (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/util/stat.js:25:19)
    at Object.checkPathsSync (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/util/stat.js:67:33)
    at Object.copySync (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:24:38)
    at File.copyTo (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/File.js:245:12)
    at FileCollection.copyTo (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js:83:17)
    at xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js:77:38
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FileCollection.copyTo (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/FileCollection.js:77:17)
    at CopyFilesTask.run (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/tasks/CopyFilesTask.js:16:20)
    at CustomTasksPlugin.runTask (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/webpackPlugins/CustomTasksPlugin.js:46:36)
    at CustomTasksPlugin.runTasks (xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/webpackPlugins/CustomTasksPlugin.js:87:21)
    at xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/webpackPlugins/CustomTasksPlugin.js:87:58
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4758) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
```

I have the following in my package.json...

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options--poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.31",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-lte": "^3.1.0",
    "dropzone": "^5.1.1",
    "jquery-contextmenu": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

and the following in my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()

    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    
    // General CSS
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/css', 'public/css')
    
    // Admin LTE Assets
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap', 'public/admin-lte/bootstrap')
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/admin-lte/dist', 'public/admin-lte')
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/admin-lte/plugins', 'public/plugins')
    
    // Context Menu
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/jquery-contextmenu', 'public/plugins/jquery-contextmenu')
    
    // Dropzone
    .copyDirectory('node_modules/dropzone/dist', 'public/plugins/dropzone')
    
    // Images
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/images', 'public/images');
```

node version v14.17.7

npm version 6.14.15

Laravel 5.8.11

I have tried deleting the cache with php artisan cache:clear then deleting the node modules folder then using 'npm install' but nothing seems to work.

I am guessing that the versions are out of synch with each other but cannot figure what I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually creating the directory 'bootstrap' in /node_modules/admin-lte/

```
mkdir node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/
```